# Chrome: Disable drag and drop of links with text

Tags: google-chrome, url, drag-and-drop

Sometimes I want to copy certain text from website (like a song name from Spotify) but because the text has a link on it Chrome will drag and drop the link (see screenshot with the "Unanswered" text from the Superuser website): 
[image]
This makes copying certain texts/words very hard to near impossible.

Is there a way to disable this behavior or an trick to get the text instead of the url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to select the text of a link you can use Alt+drag which will always enter selection mode. You may also be able to select right outside the link element on some well designed web pages but most of the time this will select more than you want. This behavior also applies to Firefox.

Comment: The Alt+drag trick only works in Chrome. In Firefox it causes a download.

Comment: Alt+drag actually worked, the idea of starting to select the selection outside the link sometimes in half of the page getting selected (when I position my cursor in front of the U of Unanswered and start selecting this happens for example), so that is most of the time not a solution. I'm not sure about the Firefox part but I guess that won't work if harrymc says so. (no problems since I don#t use Firefox)

Comment: @User025 I agree on the lack of usability of element selection in HTML. Never the less it is entering selection mode it just grabs much larger elements most of the time of modern web designs misuse of the A element among other CSS details. I'd still like to be correct on the technical aspects here though.

Comment: @harrymc The behavior you mention does not apply to the use case mentioned by the OP. Nor is it standard so if it exists its a bug and must affect your particular setup or a particular webpage which you did not mention.

Comment: Just tested it in Firefox Portable and indeed you can use Alt+drag to copy text from links. So im accepting this answer.